# Is it possible to replicate the symbiote from Spider-Man 3?

Tags: modeling, animation

[image: Example]

I wanted to recreate the symbiote, animating the tendrils and such. But, I was wondering if there is a possibility to create it.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yep, that's possible. Please read: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Answer (score 5):

You could try it with a curve:

- Create a curve to make your tentacle, snap it to the object, create a second curve (taper object) that will define the tentacle profile, hook some vertices to empties if you plan to move the tentacle:

[image]

- Bevel your curve, select the *Taper Object*, enable the *Map Taper* option:

[image]

- Animate the *Factor Start* and *End* values to make the tentacle grow along the object, duplicate your curve to create new tentacles, move and keyframe the empties if you want to animate them:

[image]

Comment: @RBlong2us, the empties are supposed to move the curve, not place it on the object, if you don't want to move the curve, you don't need them, of course  ;)